# How can I calculate the column density of Hydrogen of a galaxy?

Tags: astrophysics, density, hydrogen, galaxies

I have the following data: Mass of HI of the galaxy and radius. I thought using the following equation: $N_{HI} = \int n_{HI} ds \quad$ where the number density would be $n_{HI} = \frac{M_{HI}}{m_H V}$, where V is the volume. The problem is the volume is defined as the volume of a disk $V = \pi r^2 h$ and I do not know the height of the disk, and I don't think it would be correct to asume the galaxy is a sphere. Is there any way to obtain the height or any other way to obtain the column density?